# Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC and have just started learning it using video tutorials. I am using the latest version of Spring Tool suite
I am struck at a problem, and no solutions is working
I had to add the dependency "org.springframework spring-webmvc"
but it is not showing in the search result in the add dependency section

I searched on stackoverflow and tried the following solutions:

[Eclipse : Maven search dependencies doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work?lq=1)

[Classic error: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065478/classic-error-unable-to-update-index-for-centralhttp-repo1-maven-org-maven2)
but none of them is working fro me

Here is a pic of Error: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

the updating index box keeps loading but nothing gets downloaded. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have maven installed correctly, to get eclipse to access the maven index you need to go Window->Preferences filter for maven then tick

```
Download repository index in startup.
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but i already tried this, still doesnt work. I am using Spring tool suite

Comment: does maven work from the command line?  Do you have your settings.xml in your home/.m2 folder?