# Eclipse Maven (m2e) doesn't search or download from central

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

EDIT: I've found out, that my problem is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065478/classic-error-unable-to-update-index-for-centralhttp-repo1-maven-org-maven2).

If I want to add a dependency, which is definitely in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.java.truevfs%22%20AND%20v%3A%220.11.0%22), it doesnt find it.

My effective pom contains two entries with the id "central":

1. In repositories (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) which comes from my 'settings.xml' in my .m2-folder
2. In pluginRepositories (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2). I don't know where this entry originates from, I will find out that next (but I can exclude the 'settings.xml' and the 'pom.xml' in my project).

If i add the dependency manually, it doesn't download it.

I have checked the boxes mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work#_=_) , "download repository index on startup" was already active.

In the 'Maven repositories view', when i click 'Enable full index', it says: "Unable to set the index details due to the following error: read past EOF" (on both centrals).

How do i get central 'reconnected'?

Comment: Your https addresses contain a space between https:// and repo. Is this a copy&paste error?

Comment: Try purging you local repository run the build again.

Comment: do you have a ~/.m2/settings.xml file that's defining another repo?

Comment: @JF Meier: No, i put the spaces in there due to SOF not allowing more than 2 links for <10 reputation.

Comment: If you found the solution, please just post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Classic error: Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065478/classic-error-unable-to-update-index-for-centralhttp-repo1-maven-org-maven2)

Comment: You did notice that I edited and linked that post long before, on the first line of my post?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to this problem: Delete your cached index. It is somewhere in 
workspace\ .metadata\ .plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus (just delete the entire content of the nexus-folder). This resolved the error message "Unable to set the index details due to the following error: read past EOF".